# Is it possible to limit submit form of visitors through ->ip() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, spam-prevention

Block or limit visitor's(just viewing a website, no user registration) multiple form submission in Laravel by getting client IP and saving it in database then use it to detect spamming visitors. is that possible?

Comment: I would suggest you can try to use this package https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect, it has a laravel support as well, may be it can solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using a visitors IP to prevent future requests to your site via forms. IP's are very rarely static for the average user. If the user knows what they're doing, they'd just have to restart their internet connection and their ISP would give them a different IP address. Additionally, they could just proxy their requests utilising IP rotation to bypass your "security".

If you're trying to prevent bots from submitting forms. A good method is to implement a hidden input field with no value. If the form is submitted and the input field has been populated then you know it's a bot. It's not the most reliable method as the bot *has* to be a dumb bot.

The only truly "reliable" method I can think of is Client-Side > Server-Side validation such as Google ReCaptcha.

Ofcourse the alternate method is just accept that your form will get spammed and find a way to handle the spam after it's been submitted.

Comment: even I don't know much about how to detect bots but there is a package to detect bots which uses user-agent, I guess user agent does a better job than checking ips, this is the package https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect

Comment: I'd say it's the same level of risk tbh. When you make a request from a bot you can set the User-Agent value the bot sends to the server so you can spoof browsers easily or just create fake ones.

Comment: But I think it get the facility of if you know which Ip is causing traffic you can block or limit it by mentioning it in as regex pattern added to the $data array in Fixtures/Crawlers.php in this package